# Problems building two-way view model in SwiftUI

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I've a `MyView` that currently has a binding directly to the model. The problem is that the model represents its contents as a `Set`, while the `MyView` wants to display the contents as ordered rows (arrays). The ordering is depending on the selection that's made in the `MyView`. To keep the arrays up to date I use the `.onAppear()` modifier to prepare the array's and `.onChange()` to keep them sorted based on the selection. In code:

```
struct Container {
    var items = Set<Item>()
    var categories = [String]()
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var container: Container
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?
    @State private var categorizedItems = [String: [Item]]()

    var body: some View {
        List(container.categories, id: \.self) { category in
            RowView(category: category, items: categorizedItems[category] ?? [], selectedItem: $selectedItem)
        }
        .onAppear { categorizedItems = Dictionary(grouping: container.items, by \.category) }
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) { selectedItem in
            //Sort the arrays in categroizedItems
        }
    }
}
```

This is only a fraction of the code I need to provide the view hierarchy with the proper data. Since all I do is mangling the model data into a format that's presentable by the view I figured a layer in-between would be helpful, so I want to construct a view model that I can supply to the hierarchy using the environment.

I tried the following:

```
final class ItemsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let container: Container
    @Published var selectedItem: Item? {
        didSet { /*Basically same code as in .onChange of view*/ }
    }
    @Published private var categorizedItems = [String: [Item]]()

    init(container: container) {
        self.container = container
        categorizedItems = Dictionary(grouping: container.items, by \.category)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ItemsViewModel //Was: @Binding var container: Container
    .....
}
```

The problem is that this only works partially. Changes to the container in the model are not picked up by the view model, hence not propagated to the view, nor can I change the container in the view and have the changes propagate back to the model.

I tried changing the `let container: Container` to `@Binding var container: Container`, but the `init(container: Binding<Container>)` will give compile errors:

`self.container = container` will result in `Cannot assign value of type 'Binding<Container>' to type 'Container'`

`self.$container = container` will result in `Cannot assign to property: $container is immutable`.

Changing the view model to a struct will allow it to compile, but I can't provide it to the environment then.

To make things even more complicated, I've multiple `Containers` in my app, so the `container` in the view model might not be a simple property in the model I can write to:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData

    var body: some View {
        List {
            /* View model situation:*/
            MyView()
            .environmentObject(ItemsViewModel(modelData.containers[index]))

            /* or current (no view model) situation: */
            MyView($modelData.containers[index])

            /*Preferred situation: */
            MyView()
            .environmentObject(ItemsViewModel($modelData.containers[index]))
        }
}
```

How can I make sure that my view model keeps up to date with the model and that if I change the container from the view it propagates back to the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it so important using Set? why not normal Array?

Comment: It's actually not a `Set` but a set-like structure. Also the sorting is depending on the selection in the view, so it makes only little sense to do the sorting in the model.

Comment: I can see the point! that makes sense, plus searching for an item will we super easy and less CPU, comparing to Array.

Comment: To fix the Binding assignment error, try assigning to "self._container".  If interested I have a Gist that illustrates the use of this type of approach to map a Float? binding into a TextField to create a decimal numeric field over here https://gist.github.com/shufflingB/23daafa5253c3355cdf18934599cd54c

Comment: While for the ObservableObject's based approach - they do not automatically pass on updates when those Sources Of Truth with which they have been instantiated change. Instead, it's up to us developers to supply a timer-based, user-triggered or listening to a Combine Publisher solutions to do that as needed. An example of using a Publisher from a timer to keep a View Model up to date can be found here https://gist.github.com/shufflingB/3327aa761577de5ec52ea83f855dea2f .

Comment: The reason it probably breaks is because you are breaking the connection. The new source of truth become `categorizedItems` when to make the dictionary. I think you should have a single source for the `Container` stuff.

Comment: @shufflingb I couldn't get it to work using the self._container trick. It also feels like private API. Your timer approach looks good. I've to study that better. I also need to find a way to get values back to the model, as I can't create my model from the view model.

Comment: @RemcoPoelstra - From Python days I know the feeling about underscores prefix. For now though (afaik :-/ ) it is the only documented way to access (as a single entity) the storage created by the compiler so that it can be easily initialised in a custom init func. Can't link directly to doc's section, but if search in page for "The compiler synthesizes storage for the instance of the wrapper type by prefixing the name of the wrapped property with an underscore (_)" at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.htm you'll find it (and way way more besides :-) ).